# Is there any 'Equinox (OSGi)' like implementation for using in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, osgi, equinox, multi-module

Is there any 'Equinox (OSGi)' like implementation for using in Ruby?

I would like to use distributed multimodality with easy management in Ruby and I wasn`t able to find anything like E

Answer (score 3):

OSGi is a technology for the Java Virtual Machine, so it works with JRuby.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but is there any chance to get similar functionality outside JVM(without JRuby) and without OSGi for JVM itself?